# Jekyll with Ruby 2.3 on macOS 10.13 (HighSierra)

Tags: ruby, jekyll, macos-high-sierra

When I run `$ jekyll`or `$ jekyll serve` it raises the following error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/jekyll: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I checked `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/` and Version 2.0 does not exist. It turns out that on the same day I updated on HighSierra, Version 2.3 was installed.

I think Jekyll still looks for Version 2.0. So how can I tell Jekyll to use Ruby 2.3?

**Edit:**

When I uninstall and then install jekyll, it fails:

```
$ gem install jekyll
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20171111-1004-fgop80.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-17/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.18/gem_make.out
```

**Solution:**

I googled `can't find header files for ruby` and it turned out that "Command Line Tools for Xcode" must be installed which you can download here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

However, I have macOS 10.13 and there is no command line tools for Xcode 8.x (which was the latest version I could install). That's why I searched for Xcode in the Mac App Store and installed Xcode 9. Once, it was installed, a window popped up that said "git requires command line tools. Do you want to install it?". I clicked install and still failed to run `$gem install jekyll`.

Then I tried `$ brew doctor`. There were some warnings which I fixed one by one and finally I'm able to run `$ gem install jekyll`.

Comment: can you provide more details..? What's your `rvm`/`rbenv` version..? What's your Jekyll - project directory path (relative to your `HOME` directory)? How old is your Jekyll project (i.e. what version of Jekyll was your jekyll project directory created with?)

Comment: How about using Cloud9? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45811995/2397550

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. I just uninstalled jekyll

```
gem uninstall jekyll
```

and then installed it again.

```
gem install jekyll
```

Then it worked again.